Handling greet type of questions without llm in RAG
I'm implementing a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) system for a chatbot that handles a variety of user queries. While RAG is primarily designed to provide informative responses by retrieving relevant documents and generating responses using a language model (LLM), I want to handle certain types of queries, like greetings and polite exchanges, without resorting to the LLM for efficiency and control.
Specifically, I want to manage greet-type questions such as "Hello," "How are you?", "Good morning," etc. These questions are often formulaic and don't require the deep contextual understanding that more complex questions might. Relying on the LLM for these could be inefficient and overkill.
Is it possible to create a chatbot-like greeting exchange system without an LLM?

The RAG (and backing vector database) serve as data sources. These can be queried. However, it's the LLM which collates these data sources and converts them into what we perceive as 'an intelligible' human-like response. So unfortunately, without the LLM - a human-like interaction (the greeting exchange) would not be possible.

Alternatively, if this is simply a greeting system, an old school approach is to simply create a list of responses, and randomly serve these to the end-user. Like you mention in the question, 'These questions ... don't require the deep contextual understanding.'  However, this might to too simplistic and not what you're after.
